# R Markdown is stuck in full-screen mode

Tags: r-markdown, fullscreen

I can't seem to unlock it so I can size the screen.  Shortcut keys don't seem to work.  I am running RStudio in Kubuntu. This issue only occurs when I initiate RStudio.  I have no idea why this happened.  All other widows work properly; I can go full screen, and return.  Not sure what is going on, but it seems there must be an option somewhere in RStudio to turn this feature on and off. Anyone have an idea, please let me know?